# Сортировка по выбранным ID

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть обычный код

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FORM catalog order by id");

foreach($result as $item) {
echo $item['id'];
echo $item['name'];
}
```

Сортировка по Id. Как сделать сортировку что бы сначала шли те пункты в которых id равен 5,6,7 а потом все остальные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE (ID>=5) AND (ID<=7) UNION
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE (ID<5) UNION
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE (ID>7)
```

**Тогда все еще проще:**

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE ID IN (5,6,7) UNION
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE ID IN NOT (5,6,7)
```

Comment: Интересно, но Id может идти не по очереди 5,6,7 а еще так например 4,13,18

Comment: А на это ничто не влияет =) Запрос работает так: 
>    1) Сначала ищет все записи с ID=5, ID=6 и ID=7
>    2) Затем происходит объединение с другим запросом, который в 
>    свою очередь выводит все записи с ID<5
>    3) И, наконец, плюс еще одно объединение с запросом, который 
>    выводит все записи с ID>7

Comment: я понял как действует запрос:)
если ID идут 4,13,18
и вытаскивать все записи с 4 до 18 не будет верным решением, т.к.  залетяет те id которые не должны быть в начале.

Comment: Вы пишете : 
>    Как сделать сортировку что бы сначала шли те пункты в которых id >    равен 5,6,7

Comment: Да, но потом на практике я понял что нужные ID могут стоять в разном порядке, пардон:)

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE ID IN (1,5,7) UNION
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE ID NOT IN (1,5,7)
```

Comment: также попробуйте 
SELECT * FROM <table_name> ORDER BY FIELD(ID,1,5,7)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FORM `catalog` WHERE `id` > 5 order by id");
```

Comment: Это получается все что больше 5 идет в первую очередь. а мне нужно что бы было так
5,6,7,1,2,3,4,8,9

Comment: такое клеить надо =)

Comment: куда это)?

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FORM `catalog` WHERE `id` IN(5,6,7,1,2,3,4,8,9) ");

Comment: ну так у меня не всего 9 полей, 9 полей это было для примера. полей может быть и 1000

Comment: циклы для кого придуманы?

Comment: цыклы sql запросов не айс.

Answer (score 0):

Задача не актуальна. Если вам нужно иметь возможность в сортировке в произвольном порядке - сделайте отдельное поле в таблице и сортируйте по нему. А в этом поле уже выставляйте нужные вам значения.

а если все же хотите извратится:

```
ORDER BY id>4, id < 8, id
```

ps: я не проверял, но должно работать